# siginfo anonymous unions

Tags: c++, c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

I am trying to get the address of a system call that generates a sigsys signal! But I am getting the following error from gcc :

```
gcc emulator.c -fms-extensions
error: ‘siginfo_t’ has no member named ‘si_call_addr’
```

the code I am using is :

```
static void emulator(int nr, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *void_context)
{
        ucontext_t *ctx = (ucontext_t *)(void_context);
        int syscall;
        char *buf;
        ssize_t bytes;
        size_t len;


        if (siginfo->si_code != SYS_SECCOMP)
                return;
        if (!ctx)
                return;


        syscall = ctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_SYSCALL];
      printf("System call %d ADDR %X\n", syscall,  siginfo->si_call_addr);

        setcontext(ctx);

        return;
}
```

the si_call_addr is defined as an anonymous structure in siginfo_t.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `si_call_addr` in siginfo_t. You might be looking for the `si_addr` member.

Here's the siginfo_t provided by linux:

```
 siginfo_t {
       int      si_signo;    /* Signal number */
       int      si_errno;    /* An errno value */
       int      si_code;     /* Signal code */
       int      si_trapno;   /* Trap number that caused
                                hardware-generated signal
                                (unused on most architectures) */
       pid_t    si_pid;      /* Sending process ID */
       uid_t    si_uid;      /* Real user ID of sending process */
       int      si_status;   /* Exit value or signal */
       clock_t  si_utime;    /* User time consumed */
       clock_t  si_stime;    /* System time consumed */
       sigval_t si_value;    /* Signal value */
       int      si_int;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
       void    *si_ptr;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
       int      si_overrun;  /* Timer overrun count; POSIX.1b timers */
       int      si_timerid;  /* Timer ID; POSIX.1b timers */
       void    *si_addr;     /* Memory location which caused fault */
       long     si_band;     /* Band event (was int in
                                glibc 2.3.2 and earlier) */
       int      si_fd;       /* File descriptor */
       short    si_addr_lsb; /* Least significant bit of address
                                (since kernel 2.6.32) */
   }
```

Comment: this is not the current version.. since kernle 3.5 this has been changed to http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/include/asm-generic/siginfo.h

Comment: @GiuseppePes The struct shown here is the ABI presented to user space (in the glibc 2.16) If additional members are available, you probably do not have updated header files for use in userspace code - the link you have there shows kernel headers.